# Overlay header and bottom tabs in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Is there a way to overlay the view over the header and bottom tabs in react native? Bottom tabs and header created using the createBottomTabNavigator. So far I have used position absolute in view with all positions set to 0.
I don't want to hide the header or remove the bottom tabs from that screen, just want to overlay some view over the entire screen on some event.

```
  return (
      <View style={[styles.overlay]}></View>
 
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  overlay: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)', // 
  },
});
```

Comment: Hey, can be more specific about what you want to achieve? as also can you add some code in which you are struggling?

Comment: @007 Basically, on click of a button i want to open a view, this view should cover the entire screen. I have used position to do this, but it is not covering the header and the bottom tabs. The bottom tabs were created using createBottomTabNavigator. I have added some code

Answer (score 0):

This way you can achieve it. Use your new screen as a stack screen. Open a new screen with the click of a button it will cover your bottom bar and top header.

Add NewScreen as a new stack screen rather than using position.

```
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={stackScreenOptions}>
    <Stack.Screen name='Splash' component={Splash} />
    <Stack.Screen
      name='tab_nav_screen'
      component={TabScreen}
     />
    <Stack.Screen
      name='new_screen'
      component={NewScreen}
     />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The requirement is not to use add another stack screen. I should add the overlay on the same screen. I can use a modal and add the view inside that, but I am trying to do it without modals.

Comment: Because your stack screen is inside the bottom tab view. So the bottom tab always appears. Because your position only works for the space left for him to cover. which excludes the bottom tab.

Comment: so there is no way to do this without using models? I was just wondering how is a modal able to overlay over the bottom tab. Is it not possible to manipulate a view in such a way? Just wondering

Comment: Well, models also work on the same principle which adds a stack on top. but since it's transparent from top and bottom it feels like its opening in the same view.